# Prefill redux-form form for an update

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I'm new to React. I'm using redux-form for my app, as suggested by a tutorial.  How do you do the 'U' in CRUD with this plugin?  For an update, I call my posts_create class.  If I detect an id on this.props.params, then I assume it is an update, fetch the data, and the initialValues get set because of this function:

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
console.log ("in mapStateToProps")
console.log (state)
return {
    initialValues:state.posts.post
}
```

}

If not, it must be a create, and I don't do the fetch. Well, everything works, kinda.  After one update, the next time I go to 'New', the data from the previous update is still in the form.  I am not fetching the data.  I have tried the following in componentWillMount(), but the reset doesn't seem to work.  And this seems clumsy anyway:

```
    componentWillMount(){
    if (this.props.params.id){
        this.props.fetchPost(this.props.params.id)
        this.isNew = false;
    }
    else {
        console.log ("reseting form")
        this.props.resetForm();
        this.isNew = true;
    }
    console.log ("isNew: " + this.isNew)
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why not using `resetForm` function once your update/save completes for the first time?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a new action for the purpose of clearing  props.initialValues.  I pass the action this.props.fields, it returns an object in the correct structure, but with all of the fields properties set to empty string.  This seems convoluted, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

One Solution of it is to pass enableReinitialize={true} from parent of redux-form container class. code should look like below in Parent Class where we call redux-form container class.

```
<ReduxFormContainerClass enableReinitialize={true} />
```